# Driver Extraction Software

Tags: windows, device-driver

I am using Microsoft Deployment Toolkit to deploy Windows 7.
Before I can get this working, I need to inject a bunch of drivers (in INF file format).

Unfortunately, it is not easy to find INF files for all of my drivers therefore, is it possible to install all of my drivers onto a machine and than use software to extract the INF files for ALL installed hardware drivers?

Please suggest software that can do this (preferably free).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [DriverBackup!](http://sourceforge.net/projects/drvback/)

Just open program, click Start Backup -> Start Backup! and it will create folder "Drivers PCNAME DATE" where you will have all .inf files of your devices!

Answer (score 2):

All of the drivers should be here:

```
C:\windows\system32\DriverStore
```

DISM.exe /Image:C:\ /Add-Driver /Driver:d:\Drivers\ /Recurse

Use this to inject drivers, it works on an offline image or installation of windows.

OR point MDT to 
    C:\windows\system32\DriverStore\FileRepository

and have it get the drivers from there.